# Debugging a Python Module in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am attempting to debug code using Visual Studio Code. I have written a module 'Xchange'. I am able to run the module in the integrated terminal but I am presented with the following when attempting to run it with the debugger:

No module named Xchange

I have set the following configuration in launch.json:

```
{
 "name": "Python: Module",
 "type": "python",
 "request": "launch",
 "module": "Xchange",
 "console": "integratedTerminal",
 "cwd": "/Users/username/Documents/"
}
```

I had this working at one point, and do not believe I changed the config file. Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `Xchange` in `/Users/username/Documents/`? If not then remove that line and it should work.

Comment: @BrettCannon it is in that folder :)

Comment: Then please open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .